# Run-time vs develop-time dependencies in R

Tags: r, r-package

I'm developing a package (`golem`) in R, and it returns a `NOTE` about excess package in an `Import` (`DESCRIPTION`):

> checking package dependencies … NOTE
> Imports includes 34 non-default packages.
> Importing from so many packages makes the package vulnerable to any of
> them becoming unavailable. Move as many as possible to Suggests and
> use conditionally.

I have allocated some packages in `Suggests` (`DESCRIPTION`), like this:

```
usethis::use_package(package = "ggplot2", type = "Suggests")
usethis::use_package(package = "MASS", type = "Suggests")
```

I would like to know :

- What is the difference between `Imports` (run-time) vs `Suggests` (develop-time) and if the latter has anything to do with the term "compile time" of other programming languages.
- How do I know a package is needed by the user at runtime? Is there any universal rule for this (like a phrase to help you know)? And for `Suggests`?

Comment: You "know" a user needs it at runtime when they call a function from your package that needs its functionality. If that part is optional, then you "know" when they explicitly set a function argument or set an option (`options(..)`) that explicitly says that they prefer something to be done with another package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In R, packages listed in the `Imports` clause of the `DESCRIPTION` file must be available or your package won't load.  Normally they will all be loaded when your package is loaded, though it's possible to delay that by not importing anything, just using `::` notation to access them.

Packages listed in the `Suggests` clause don't need to be available, and won't be automatically loaded.  To access their functions, you normally call `requireNamespace()` to find out if the package is available, and if so use `::` for access.  If it is not available, your package should fail gracefully in whatever the user was trying to do, letting them know that they need to install the missing package if they want the task to succeed.

These aren't really "run-time" versus "develop-time" differences.  It's all run-time.

There are two things in R that might be called "compile-time" in other languages.  The best match is installing your package.  That configures it to the particular R version and platform it is running on.  R also has a "just-in-time" compiler that optimizes functions, but other than a bit of a speed increase that is pretty much invisible to the user.

I think @r2evans answered your second question clearly in a comment:  the user needs a package to use functions that use that package.  If some of your functions that use it are unlikely to be used by most users, use `Suggests`, and add the test.

Comment: There is some danger to it, but I feel like usethis / roxygen should have a feature that would allow you to automatically copy functions from other packages to your package, something like `usethis::use_static_import(package_you_want_to_steal_from::function_you_want_to_steal)`, that would then copy the function definition including roxygen comments to your source directory, take care of the licenses & adds a field `#@stolenFrom package_you_want_to_steal_from::function_you_want_to_steal` that instructs roxygen to add a link/note to the .Rd file and warns you if upsteam changed/offers an update.